# Comparar columnas contra un int

Tags: mysql

tengo un problema, y es que necesito comparar una serie de valores de tipo entero o numerico, pero esto lo debo hacer en mysql, y en un vista, no puedo usar cursores

`objetivo < (select (monto) from pedido inner join empleado on empleado=codigoC inner join oficina on ofina = CodOfina group by CodOfina)`

ese select devuelve varias columnas, y necesito compararas contra la columna objetivo, para saber si son mayor o menor

gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Para una pregunta de base de datos, los demás no podemos ser de ayuda si no nos muestras: las tablas sobre las que estás trabajando (en este caso, para crear la vista), unos datos de prueba y el resultado esperado al usarlo. Por favor, edita tu pregunta e incluye esta información (como texto, para poder replicar tus problemas sin tener que transcribir desde una imagen)

Comment: En SQL para comparar se usa `WHERE`. Si quieres traer las filas cuyo `monto` sea menor a `objetivo` tendrías que poner esto en la consulta: `SELECT ... FROM ... INNER JOIN ... WHERE monto < objetivo GROUP BY ...` donde se asume que `objetivo` es un valor en bruto o de una columna de alguna tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Si es que entendi bien tu pregunta puedes hacer uso de la funcion `case` para indicar si el monto es mayor que el objetivo con valor 1 en caso contrario 0

Ejemplo:

```
select monto,CASE
    WHEN monto > objetivo THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END as isMayor
from pedido inner join empleado on empleado=codigoC inner join oficina on ofina = CodOfina group by CodOfina
```